# android studio: cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, android

I am unable to identify the problem. The `songCollection.searchById` (`songCollection` is always underlined red) saying that the symbol cannot be identified even though I already have a `SongCollection` class.

```
public void handleSelection(View view) {
    String resourceId = AppUtil.getResourceId(getContext(), view);
    Song selectedSong = songCollection.searchById(resourceId);

    AppUtil.popMessage(getContext(), "Streaming Song: " + selectedSong.getTitle());

    sendDataToActivity(selectedSong);
}
```

song collection class

```
public class SongCollection {
   private Song[] songs = new Song[5];

   public SongCollection() {
    prepareSong();
   }
```

Therefore, I cannot play my application or make my songs clickable

Answer (score 1):

May be you did not instantiate SongSelection anywhere like this:

```
SongSelection songSelection = new SongSelection();
```